# Could not decrypt data exception thrown using Google API Client for Java

Tags: java, blogger, google-api-java-client, pkcs#12

Using the google-api-client for Java I am attempting to authenticate to a service account mirroring the process outlined in the sample code http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/storage-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/storage/serviceaccount/cmdline/StorageServiceAccountSample.java in order to use the Blogger api. I have created the service account and downloaded the .p12 file provided by the API dashboard.  This .p12 file is stored as a resource in the jar file housing the code intended to connect to the Blogger service.  Upon running the setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File on the GoogleCredentials.Builder object I encounter an IOException with a message simply indicating that 'it' could not decript data.  The following is a snippit of the code in question (with file names removed) and the chunk of the stack trace which I think is germane. I'm at something of a loss concerning the cause of this exception.  Using openssl I am able to verify the p12 file in isolation.

### Code

```
httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

File p12File = File.createTempFile("filename", ".p12");
FileOutputStream p12FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(p12File);
IOUtils.copy(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ACCESS-KEYS/filename.p12"), p12FileOutputStream);

p12FileOutputStream.close();

credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(BloggerScopes.BLOGGER))
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12File)
            .build();
```

### Stack Trace

```
java.io.IOException: Could not decrypt data.
at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.b(Unknown Source)
at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.a(Unknown Source)
at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.a(Unknown Source)
at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.a(Unknown Source)
at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.a(Unknown Source)
at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1183)
at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:77)
at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:110)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(GoogleCredential.java:503)
```

Comment: I don't see any errors in your code. Maybe something wrong with crypto provider setup, you're using `com.rsa.jsse.JsseProvider` as default, it is strange choice. Try to load keystore programmatically before pass to GoogleCredentialBuilder, explicitly set SunJSSE provider.  `Keystore.getInstance("PKCS12", "SunJSSE")`

Comment: Nice - that seems to have done the trick.  I'm not sure where my original default was getting established but forcing it to use SunJSSE as the provider alleviates the exception.  If you convert your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @PaulMichelotti - can you submit final version of the code? I'm solving the same problem and not sure where to pass KeyStore object after obtaining new instance...

Comment: @ JuraKhrapunov, I've added an answer with the final version of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the final code here based on the response provided by [user1516873](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1516873/user1516873) above.  Note, the germane difference between this and the original question is line 3 where "SunJSSE" is set explicitly.

```
httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "SunJSSE");
keyStore.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ACCESS-KEYS/filename.p12"), "notasecret".toCharArray());
        PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("privatekey", "notasecret".toCharArray());

credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)      
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(BloggerScopes.BLOGGER))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(key)
                .build();
```